# NSWindow Background Magnify

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

I know it is possible to blur the background of an NSWindow, but is it possible to magnify whatever is behind the window and show it, or even do the same for the window's content view?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Apple's example **CIAnnotation**. You can download sample code from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CIAnnotation/Introduction/Intro.html).

CIAnnotation app example:

[image]

References and guides which can help You with this:

[Core Image Programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html)
[Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html)
[NSGraphicsContext Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSGraphicsContext_Class/Reference/Reference.html)